# Why am I getting these errors on a fresh Laravel install?

Tags: php, laravel

These errors:

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelChallenge\public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelChallenge\public\index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelChallenge\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelChallenge\public\index.php on line 24
```

All I did was create a fresh Laravel project using `laravel new` and navigate to `public/index.php`...

Comment: Did you run `composer install`?

Comment: try regenerating autoload file using `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Check php version

Comment: If you're using `php artisan serve` you should not include `/public/index.php` in your url. If not then male sure you've set up your virtual host properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1:**
You need to regenerate autoload.php file. you can use dump-autoload to do that without having to go through an install or update.

use

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to generate autoload.php file again in /vendor directory.

**Case 2:  Issue with composer install command**

Sometimes when you run: "composer install" you got that error too, so the best option is first run: "composer install --no-scripts" and then run composer install normally.

**Case 3: Composer broke while update**

There was an update to composer that broke things. The fix is to update your composer.json file.

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5066

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3687

Comment: Turn out I forgot to run`composer install`!